# Search not showing all results

Tags: web8, cme, search

Search is not working properly while searching the content in one of the SG.
The SG has many pages and other SGs. When we search for a empty value, it returns only 10 results. 
Also, the SG has one child SG as 'H10'. When we search 'H10' we get no results.

This happens only for this particular SG. it works fine for all other content.

P.S. We have not re-indexed the search. Newly added items do appear in search.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide some more detail about  if you have optimized your search index and/or tried to reindex it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your search service(s) were not running when those items were created or updated, thus preventing those items from appearing in your search results.

Try forcing a reindex using the `Sync-TcmSearchIndex` PowerShell cmdlet, as explained on the [Reindexing search indexes](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-585D5C74-14E0-4E5C-A6A4-8C48B8E188CC) page in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Please make note that search functionality can be misleading. It is not working with correct data, but with indexed data to have better performance. That being said, your search is only correct if its up to date with latest changes in content.
To fix this issue, please reindex your data to refresh changes. After this you should be able to see old items in search.